# Application Error on Android Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, apk, screen-rotation

Im testing a simple html file with some input fields and two buttons, after installing the apk file on my android device everything seems well, but when I rotate the screen I receive the following error
[image]

Im using a samsung galaxy s3 mini with android 4.1.2.

Im using the latest phonegap and eclipse juno.

How can I fix (or hide) this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"` to your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml, like recommended in the [PhoneGap API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)